# Random function triggering $digest() error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on my first angular app and am getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

I think I've isolated the source to my use of the random() function. This seems to make sense in terms of what I read about this error (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/705). However, I don't know how to avoid this error.

I've recreated the error with this simple code:

randtest.js:

```
   function FirstCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.randNum= function(){
        var rando = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        return rando;
      };      
    }
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="randtest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
      <h1>{{randNum()}}</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the $scope property directly to the function. Let the scope property reference the function's result:

```
var r = function(){
    var rando = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    return rando;
  }; 
$scope.randomNum =r();
```

HTML:

```
<h1>{{randomNum}}</h1>
```

[Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2hXbxeGz6gksE0ubRrDS?p=preview)

**Update** - NOT wrapping the calculation in a function also seems to avoid the error:

```
$scope.randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
```

The reasoning why the error occurs is beyond me...

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned normally occurs when you create a **loop of changes over** a property.

For example, like when you watch for changes on a certain property and then change the value of that property on the listener.
Make sure that your code doesn't have this kind of situations.