# angularjs make random placeholder on input

Tags: angularjs, random, iteration, placeholder, digest

I tried to make random placeholder text on input.
here is my [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10280/)

try to Run this sample several times, then you may see error code through console.

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
```

even tho placeholder text changed, bother this error message.
why this code sometimes works, sometimes not works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14381445/3199310) answer:

> You shouldn't change objects/models during the render or otherwise it
>   will force a new render (and consequently a loop, which causes the
>   'Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!').
>
> If you wan to update the model, do it on the Controller or on a
>   Directive, never on the view. angularjs documentation recommends not
>   to use the ng-init exactly to avoid these kind of situations:
>
> Use ngInit directive in templates (for toy/example apps only, not
>   recommended for real applications)

- [bmleite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651480/bmleite)

Answer (score 0):

Your Random function triggering $digest() error
Here is the issue in angular js about it:-

[Random function triggering $digest() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562390/random-function-triggering-digest-error)

And i searched but there is no way to work around i find.